# How do I obtain (view) the virtual keyboard in the AVD (SDK 4.2)?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to understand the source-code of a keyboard application on the Android Platform and hence it is highly essential that I use the **virtual keyboard only** instead of my laptop keyboard to input text on the virtual device.

So far I have been unable to launch a virtual keyboard on my "Galaxy Nexus" AVD.
Can anybody give me a quick fix to this problem?

Here is a screenshot of what I see in the latest version of the platform-tools (rev 21) in the new AVD [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the latest version of the platform-tools (revision 21), then create a new AVD to get the new creation dialog.  You can select a Galaxy Nexus in the device dropdown, and it should then "just work."

If you have the older platform-tools dialog, there's an option you can add in the window at the bottom to make the virtual keyboard appear.  It's something like "hardware keyboard available" and set that to false.  I don't remember what it's called exactly because I don't have the old dialog available anymore.

I highly recommend using the new one though, it's much easier to get emulators that resemble real devices.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the the new AVD that you have mentioned in your answer, but I still have to use my hardware keyboard. The virtual keyboard needs to appear there instead!

Comment: Did you create that AVD using the new tools, or did you create it with an older version?  Also, it's using hardware controls, so uncheck that box in the creation dialog, also make sure the "hardware keyboard present" box is NOT checked.

Comment: Hey Thanks Ralgha! I had to just go to the config.ini file and change the hw.keyboard to "no" !
Thanks for the prompt replies! :)